# How it can be made a spherical cap surface with qgis raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I would like to make a test in QGIS raster calculation: I'd like to make in a flat raster surface (0m as elevation) a kind of hill or dome with the spherical cap geometry formula.

`P` is the point vertex projection of the height in the base of the cap, the coordinates of which are `x, y`.

[image: from flat raster to hill]

Could anyone help me?